# Removing strings between two delimiters

Tags: java, delimiter

I have some code that reads in two texts files (one contains words to be removed and the other contains data collected from Twitter). In my program, i've encompassed the Twitter user name between delimiters, so that i can remove them (as well as the stop words) at later stage.

My code (below) perfectly removes the stop words from the data, but i'm stumped on how to remove the strings between the two delimiters. I have a feeling that the inbuilt function of indexOf() maybe best suited for it, but i'm not sure how to implement it with my current code. Here is an example test case that removes the delimiters, twitter handle and stop words:

Input:

```
--/--RedorDead :--/-- Tottenham are the worst team in existence
```

Output:

```
Tottenham worst team existence
```

My code:

```
    Scanner stopWordsFile = new Scanner(new File("stopwords_twitter.txt"));
    Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));

    // Create a set for the stop words (a set as it doesn't allow duplicates)
    Set<String> stopWords = new HashSet<String>();
    // For each word in the file
    while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) {
        stopWords.add(stopWordsFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    // Creates an empty list for the test.txt file
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    // For each word in the file
    while (textFile.hasNext()) {
        words.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    // Create an empty list (a list because it allows duplicates) 
    ArrayList<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Iterate over the list "words" 
    for(String word : words) {
        // If the word isn't a stop word, add to listOfWords list
        if (!stopWords.contains(word)) {
            listOfWords.add(word);
        }

    stopWordsFile.close();
    textFile.close();

    for (String str : listOfWords) {
        System.out.print(str + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Why has `"are the"` been removed?

Comment: Because they're words in the stopword_twitter text file that also need to be removed.

Comment: But as i said in the description, my existing code already does this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex replace with a reluctant quantifier:

```
str = str.replaceAll("--/--.*?--/--\\s*", "");
```

The expression `*?` is a *reluctant* quantifier, which means it matches as *little* as possible while still matching, which in turn means it will stop at the next delimiter after the first in case there are multiple delimiter pairs in the input.

I added `\s*` to the end to also remove trailing spaces after the closing delimiter (which your example seemed to suggest was wanted).

---

To use this approach, you're going to have to read the text file *line* at a time, rather than *word* at a time, process the line to remove the username then split into words:

```
while (textFile.hasNextLine()) {
    for (string word : textFile.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("--/--.*?--/--\\s*", "").split("\\s+")) {
        words.add(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: That not only removes the delimiters, but the text between them too?

Comment: @Bean it removes as per question: delimiters and everything between

Comment: Ahh, i see! And would i put this in the for loop at the bottom of the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String remove(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\s*--\\/-.*?)--\\/--", "").trim();
}
```

*Input:* `"--/--RedorDead :--/-- Tottenham are the worst team in existence --/--RedorDead :--/-- Tottenham are the worst team in existence"`

*Output:* `"Tottenham are the worst team in existence Tottenham are the worst team in existence"`

[Demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZShkFr/1)